# Jquery .load for update fragment on flask\python

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, flask

I'm trying to use jquery .load in my flash application to update the div, but that does not work.

routes.py

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def red():  
    return redirect('/index.html')

@app.route('/index.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', title='Estat')
```

index.html

```
 <script>
     function run() {
    $( "#display" ).load( "/index.html #display" );
    }

    setInterval(run, 1000);
    </script>

<div id="display"><h1>word 2</h1></div>
```

I want each time when changing the template file in a time interval the content of the div block changes. Help me pls.

Comment: That script works fine without flask+python. I think the problem is with the index.html

Comment: Can you mark my answer as accepted so that I know i have answered your question successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you're on the right track. The div should be reloading correctly, if not try wrapping it in adding body and head tags, that helped me one time. It is now up to you to return any data you want to the webpage. Say you want to display time:
In python import the datetime module using : `import datetime`
and make it the  index function with:

```
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', title='Estat', time = str(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

then modify your div to be:
    `<div id="display"><h1>{{ time}}</h1></div>`

now your webpage should be returning the time, and refreshing every second

Comment: remember, try wrapping the html in proper body and head tags ;For example it should look like ;`<html><head>JAVASCRIPT HERE</head <body>DIV HERE</body></html>

Comment: its works for variable, but not for changes in template file. For example i change text on <h1>Time {{ time}}</h1> in notepad & save this. I'm not rebooting the server and the site needs to see the changes, but this does not happen

Comment: I think it's all about caching templates with debugging mode off

Comment: Yeah i think you need to restart the server to see template changes, otherwise use debug mode